# image upload resolution problems

Tags: java, image, io

when i am uploading an image with image io it is converting the resolutions of the image

what i mean to say is i am uploading a image with 300 dpi it get converts into 96 dpi why?

i am not using any resizing

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to have correct punctuation and capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Guess, you don't copy image metadata, here goes simplistic example how this can be done:

```
ImageInputStream iis =ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File("test.jpg"));
ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis).next();
reader.setInput(iis, true);

IIOMetadata meta = reader.getImageMetadata(0);

BufferedImage image = reader.read(0);

/*
do image manipulations here
 */

ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("out.jpg"));
ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWriter(reader);
writer.setOutput(ios);

writer.write(meta, new IIOImage(image, null, null), null);
```

*Since you've not provided any specific details, i've tested it on local files. However, i hope that it provides you a hint.*